# How to access a number in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7, pandas-loc

All,

I have a df that looks like this

```
     lib1m   markdate     tag  purpose currencyBench
0 -0.08900 2018-03-01   LIBOR  REUTERS           JPY
1  0.49663 2018-03-01   LIBOR  REUTERS           GBP
2 -0.59900 2018-03-01  STIBOR  REUTERS           SEK
3 -0.37100 2018-03-01   LIBOR     ECON           EUR
4  1.42000 2018-03-01  OBFR01    ECON5           USD
```

To access the number i am looking for i did this:

```
rates.loc[(rates['currencyBench']=='GBP') ,['lib1m']]
```

However, the output is

```
     lib1m
1  0.49663
```

but what I am looking for is `0.49663` without column name and the index.

Any idea is more than welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rates.loc[rates['currencyBench']=='GBP', 'lib1m'].iloc[0]`.

`pd.DataFrame.iloc` is used for integer indexing.

In this case, indexing with 0 will extract the first element of your `pd.Series`.